# What does it mean to say a web crawler is I/O bound and not CPU bound?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, io, web-crawler

I've seen this in some answers on S/O where the point is made that the programming language doesn't matter as much for a crawler and so C++ is overkill vs say Python. Can someone please explain this in layman's terms so that there's no ambiguity about what is implied? Clarification of the underlying assumption here is also appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have spent any time crawling the web this is brutally obvious.  It takes very little CPU to suck HTML down, but most of your time is spent waiting for network IO to finish.  Therefore if you routinely have multiple pages to crawl, invest time in an asynchronous crawling algorithm.

Comment: I believe the correct terminology is "I/O bound"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that I/O is the bottleneck here. The act of going out to the net to retrieve a page (I/O) is slower than analysing the page (CPU).

So, making the CPU bit ten times faster will have little effect on the overall time taken. On the other hand, doubling the I/O speed *will* have a very beneficial effect, right up to the point where CPU starts being the bottleneck.

Comment: ... and unless you're doing some serious number crunching, this is pretty much always going to be the case

Comment: Keep in mind that parsing and analysing the downloaded page consists also of I/O, even if the source is RAM, not network. Getting data from memory to CPU (and back) would most likely still be slower than actually processing it in CPU.

Comment: I think these days the markup for most any page would fit in cache, so the analysis would satisfy any useful definition of being done "on the CPU". And since the process of fetching data from RAM cannot be controlled or even directly observed by the application programmer, and CPU-RAM transfers have entirely different usage patterns and performance characteristics from peripheral I/O, bringing it up here only serves to confuse matters.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the program takes more time reading and writing (via disk or network) then it does actually running the algorithms in the code. I/O is vastly slower than most CPUs, and using it will usually slow down a program greatly.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add is that during Input/Output operations your program (unless poorly written) isn't actively using the CPU, it's in inactive state (sleep).